# Overloading string with cout operator

Tags: c++, string, overloading, cout

I'm trying to overload the `<<` when it receives a `string`. I want that if the `string` is lets say `Mark`, it prints instead `Dog`. I know it doesn't make sense for you but this is what I need.
I've tried this but it does not work.

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, string& a);
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, string& a){
     std::cout << "I love dogs";
     return out;
}

int main(){
    std::cout<<"I love cats";
    return 0;
}
```

I want it to change every single `string` no matter where I use the function `std::cout <<` string and for it to instead printing what `String` is, it would always print `Dog` instead.

My problem is that instead of printing `Dog`, it keeps on printing the `string` given. Like it keeps printing `I love cats` instead of `I love dogs`

I already tried:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const char* a){
    std::cout << "I love dogs";
   return out;
}
```

Instead but it give me segmentation fault.

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const char* &a);
```

And this one keeps on printing `I love cats`

Comment: That instead of printing Dog it just keeps on printing the string given in the first place. Like std::cout << string doesnt call the overload function

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of what you are doing, because the given code would print `Dog`, if you do `std::string str = "ok"; std::cout << str << std::endl;` and have your `std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, string& a)` defined before that. As can be seen in this  [wandbox demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UMnKKjN4O4k9vomi)

Comment: Ok already edit it. And thats what happens it doesnt change what its printing, like it doesnt even call the overload function

Comment: The `"I love cats"` in `std::cout<<"I love cats";` is not a `std::string` but a `const char*`.

Comment: `"I love cats"` is not an `std::string`, it is a `const char[]`

Comment: Standard implementations for `operator<<` already exist for `const char*` and `std::string`, you can't overload or override them with your own implementations.  Find another solution. For instance, you could write a custom [`std::basic_streambuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) descendant that does the desired string substitution when it is written to, and then assign an instance of that class to `std::cin` via its [`rdbuf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) method. Then all calls to `cin << ...` will go through your class

Comment: If I do it give const char it throws me segmentation fault

Comment: Well yes, because `std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const char* a)` will call itself recursively because `std::cout << "I love dogs";` passes a `const car*` to `cout`  so you create an infinite resursive call.

Comment: Oh you right, thanks!!, I used printf inside the overload instead to make sure it didn't call it recursively.

Comment: Using `printf` or `std::cout` within a `std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, …)` is a bad idea. The `std::ostream& operator <<  (std::ostream &out, …)` is not only used for `std::cout` but for any output stream. So what you essentially do is that you pipe any output to the stream to `std::cout`, you always have to use your first argument: `std::ostream &out`, to output the data. So for your code, if you would try to write a string to a file using a `fstream`, then the string would not appear in the file but in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that your custom `operator<<` will call the default operator and not call itself. You can do this by using a namespace qualifier on the overloaded operator (`std::operator<<`). Also, string literals are `const char []` and not `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const char *) {
  return std::operator<<(os, "I love dogs\n");
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "I love cats\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should embrace your code with a **namespace std** for a properly defined operator<<(...) method for iostream.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace std {
    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const char *) {
        return std::operator<<(os, "I love dogs\n");
    }
}

int main() {
   std::cout << "I love cats\n";
}
```